# How do I prevent Widgets.exe from getting automatically started on Windows 11?

Tags: windows, windows-11, widgets

How do I gracefully prevent `Widgets.exe` from starting automatically on my Windows 11?

By "gracefully", I mean I don't like deleting it or messing with the filesystem security.

It's already turned off in my Task bar settings:

[image]

I've tried [`Autoruns`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) but `Widgets` isn't listed in any of the typical autoruns locations.

It isn't a big deal, but I don't like the fact that a heavy `WebView2`-based app is setting there in the memory and doing nothing useful to me as a user:

[image]

Comment: Did you check `services.msc` and see if it can be disabled there?

Comment: @Nelson, I checked and there's nothing there matching `widgets`. I would have spotted it with Autoruns, it also has `Services` tab.

Comment: Open Task Manager and go to the Startup Tab, right click on Widgets.exe and select disable. Then reboot. If it does not show in task manager use Autoruns software to  disable it from starting>>>>https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns

Comment: @Moab, thanks but sadly it is not there in Task Manager. I did mention Autoruns in the question.

Comment: See if anything here helps>>>https://gadgetstouse.com/blog/2021/07/15/disable-widgets-on-windows-11/

Comment: @Moab, I already have `TaskbarDa` set to `0` at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced`. That's what the Toolbar setting on the pic in my question does.

Comment: Try in `gpedit.msc` > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Widgets, to set "Allow widgets" to Disabled, then reboot. If you don't see the "Widgets" section, this [link](https://www.pdq.com/blog/how-to-remove-widgets-in-windows-11/) tells how to install it.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I have the answer! Very simple in fact when you know.
run PowerShell as administrator and `winget uninstall "windows web experience pack"`. And voilà!

If you want to reinstall it for some x or y reason. You can install it again from the Microsoft Store https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-web-experience-pack/9mssgkg348sp

Now enjoy your extra RAM and off fans!

Comment: it did remove Widget.exe for me

Comment: Re @KasparL.Palgi: https://gist.github.com/noseratio/40965eb5c3645fe8bf2b9bb6298d1c83

Comment: Thanks for the uninstall answer.  My 2021 Intel NUC started using more CPU and spinning up the fan after my upgrade to Windows 11, and caught widgets.exe in the act today.

Comment: winget is not detected as a name of commandlet

Comment: @Anixx winget.exe is part of the package Desktop App Installer. If you removed that, then that's why you don't have it. That's the reason people shouldn't be removing things without understanding what they are doing.